# Issue with AudioInputStream for MP3 files

Tags: java, audio, javafx, mp3

I have been trying to play an MP3 file in Java for a while now. I have tried JavaFX MediaPlayer, JlGui, and JavaLayer. The issue with the JavaFX MediaPlayer is, from what I have ascertained, that the libav-55 file is missing. That, however, is not my main issue. My main issue is that whenever I try to do MP3 files, the issue I always get is the AudioInputStream. I understand that it does not support MP3 files, and only supports raw WAV, but I don't have a solution to this. Does anyone have any ideas for how to play an MP3 file without an AudioInputStream, using JavaLayer?

Also, if anyone has a fix for the JavaFX issue, that would be accepted too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your question title, but system requirements for MP3 playback on Linux using JavaFX are listed in the [Oracle Java 8 certified configurations page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html).

Comment: My computer is compatible with all of these..

Comment: Why do you think there is a file missing?  Why do you think it is libav-55?  It is not a file listed as required on the certified configurations page.  When it is correctly setup, JavaFX will play MP3 files without issue.

Comment: I thought JavaLayer (JavaZoom) lets you convert MP3 to wav. So you would feed the mp3 to JavaLayer and take the wav output and feed that in turn to an AudioInputStream.

Comment: @jewelsea, the reason I think that is because of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768613/javafx-media-player-crashes-when-opening-mp3s-even-though-libav-53-libraries-are

Comment: If you are running a certified configuration and JavaFX MP3 playback is not working, then that is a bug, which you can report at: [http://bugreport.java.com](http://bugreport.java.com).  Include complete environment information (Java runtime version used, OS used, av libraries installed), a link to sample MP3 file, complete error traces, a minimal sample application which replicates the issue with full media error handling as defined in the [media javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html).